# Make a involute gear

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mechanism

Quick question:

Has anyone been able to make a involute gear with a simple code?
I would like to have a 2D plot, but it is very difficult.

Comment: To understand what you mean by "simple code," you'll have to give us an example of the code you've tried and point out what is not sufficiently simple about it.

Comment: I believe to have seen a website devoted to gears. It has Mathematica code too. Will be trying to find it again.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Thank you. That would be great.

Comment: Also potentially of interest: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/customer-stories/optimizing-face-gear-surfaces-in-mathematica.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](http://bugman123.com/Gears/) devoted to all kinds of strange and less strange gear systems has at least one Mathematica 4.2 programs.

Two pictures from this page:

[image]

[image]

There are also various demonstration projects, for instance [MechanicalInvoluteGears](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MechanicalInvoluteGears/) and [MeshingInvoluteGearTeeth](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MeshingInvoluteGearTeeth/).
On [MathSource](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3021/), you'll find related code.